# Refactoring a Django form which renders fields manually

Tags: html, django

I'm working on a code base which contains forms which are written along the lines of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually. Here is a snippet of the form's template, which uses [Django Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks):

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.session_number|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {% if form.session_number.errors %}
      <span id="{{ form.session_number.id_for_label }}-error" class="error">{{ form.session_number.errors|join:", " }}</span>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="{{ form.session_number.id_for_label }}"
        class="{% if form.session_number.value %}active{% endif %} {% if form.name.errors %}invalid{% endif %}">
      Session Number
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <label for="email">Scheduled For</label>
  </div>
  {{ form.scheduled_for }}
</div>

{% if form.family.value %}
  <input name="family" required="" id="id_family" type="hidden" value="{{ form.family.value }}" />
{% else %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">

      {{ form.family|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
      {% if form.family.errors %}
        <span id="{{ form.family.id_for_label }}-error" class="error">
          {{ form.family.errors|join:", " }}
        </span>
      {% endif %}
      <label for="{{ form.family.id_for_label }}" class="{% if form.family.errors %}invalid{% endif %}">
        Family
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.expert|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {% if form.expert.errors %}
      <span id="{{ form.expert.id_for_label }}-error" class="error">
        {{ form.expert.errors|join:", " }}
      </span>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="{{ form.expert.id_for_label }}" class="{% if form.expert.errors %}invalid{% endif %}">
      Expert
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.session_type|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {% if form.session_type.errors %}
      <span id="{{ form.session_type.id_for_label }}-error" class="error">
        {{ form.session_type.errors|join:", " }}
      </span>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="{{ form.session_type.id_for_label }}" class="{% if form.session_type.errors %}invalid{% endif %}">
      Session Type
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.status|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {% if form.status.errors %}
      <span id="{{ form.status.id_for_label }}-error" class="error">
        {{ form.status.errors|join:", " }}
      </span>
    {% endif %}
    <label for="{{ form.status.id_for_label }}" class="{% if form.status.errors %}invalid{% endif %}">
      Status
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is how the corresponding part of the form looks:

[image]

As you can see, the code is far from DRY, and there is also coupling between the `django.forms.Form` class and the template: whenever you add a field to the former, you need to add a corresponding `<div class="row">` to the template.

I'm considering whether to refactor this code using, for example, a custom renderer as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/renderers/#the-low-level-render-api. I'm vacillating whether this would be worthwhile, however, because blogs like https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html actually describe how to gain more control over the form by rendering fields manually.

My question is: would it be possible to obtain the same 'look and feel' of the form using a simple template such as

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

with an appropriate form renderer? Or are there other ways to reduce code duplication in this example?

Comment: Do you really need to render each row individually? Can’t you just [loop over the form’s fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)? You might find django-crispy-forms useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up still adding fields manually, but defining some custom filters to reduce code repetition in the templates. Here is the corresponding template snippet after refactoring:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load custom_errors label_with_classes %}
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.session_number|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {{ form.session_number|custom_errors }}
    {{ form.session_number|label_with_classes }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <label for="email">Scheduled For</label>
  </div>
  {{ form.scheduled_for }}
</div>

{% if form.family.value %}
  <input name="family" required="" id="id_family" type="hidden" value="{{ form.family.value }}" />
{% else %}
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      {{ form.family|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
      {{ form.family|custom_errors }}
      {{ form.family|label_with_classes }}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.expert|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {{ form.expert|custom_errors }}
    {{ form.expert|label_with_classes }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.session_type|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {{ form.session_type|custom_errors }}
    {{ form.session_type|label_with_classes }}
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.status|add_error_class:"invalid" }}
    {{ form.status|custom_errors }}
    {{ form.status|label_with_classes }}
  </div>
</div>
```

where the `custom_errors` filter is defined in `templatetags/custom_errors.py` as follows:

```
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def custom_errors(bound_field):
    return mark_safe(f'<span id="{bound_field.id_for_label}-error" \
                     class="error">{", ".join(bound_field.errors)}</span>' if bound_field.errors else '')
```

and the custom label tags are defined in `templatetags/label_with_classes.py`:

```
from django import template
from django.forms import ChoiceField, BooleanField, DateField
from titlecase import titlecase

register = template.Library()


def pretty_name(name):
    """Convert 'first_name' to 'First Name'."""
    return titlecase(name.replace('_', ' '))


def should_be_active(bound_field):
    '''Determine whether the field's label should have Material's "active" class added to it'''
    return (bound_field.value() and not isinstance(bound_field.field, (ChoiceField, BooleanField)))\
        or isinstance(bound_field.field, DateField)


@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def label_with_classes(bound_field, contents=None):
    '''Extend Django's label_tag() method to provide the appropriate Materialize CSS classes'''
    active = 'active' if should_be_active(bound_field) else ''
    invalid = 'invalid' if bound_field.errors else ''
    classes = f"{active} {invalid}".strip()
    contents = contents or pretty_name(bound_field.name)
    return bound_field.label_tag(attrs={'class': classes},
                                 contents=contents,
                                 label_suffix='')
```

This makes the code somewhat more concise and also make explicit some of the logic behind the 'copy-pasting' of individual fields.